# How do I fix boot error "Kernel requires a 86-64 cpu"?

Tags: boot-failure, architecture

My desktop pc gives the following error when trying to install from a cd:

```
Kernel requires a 86-64 cpu only detected a i686 cpu unable to boot
```

My pc is a Medion, 160GB hard drive, Pentium 4 processor, 512MB memory. I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 from the (complete manual magazine).

Comment: Here is the link for [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 32bit](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)

Answer (score 11):

You appear to be trying to run an `amd64` (64 bits) build on a 32-bits PC. Download an `i386` (32 bits) CD image instead from [ubuntu.com/download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and make sure to select "32 bits" as the flavour.

The CD you have there will run fine on more recent hardware, though.